# Convert flattened yaml to hierarchical yaml in Java

Tags: java, yaml, flatten

Is it possible to convert flattened yaml structure to hierarchical using java?

**My Input** (flattened yaml) :

```yaml
person.address.city: Paris
person.address.zipcode: 75000
person.address.country: France
```

**Expected output** (hierarchical yaml) :

```yaml
---
person:
  address:
    city: Paris
    zipcode: 75000
    country: France
```

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I started with converting my flatted yaml to json using com.github.wnameless dependency but I think it's not a good way !

Comment: It might not be as efficient as it could be, but if you expect everything to work like with that JSON utility you referenced, transforming your YAML into JSON, processing the JSON with that module, and then transforming it back to YAML might be the simplest solution.